# program to choose 4 columns from 5 column matrix and find determinant in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, determinants

How can I make a program in MATLAB that will choose 4 columns out of a 5 column matrix and find the determinant from that new 4x4 matrix?

I tried setting each column as a vector with a variable:

```
a = [1; 2; 3; 4];
b = [5; 6; 7; 8]
c = [9; 0; 1; 2];
d = [3; 4; 5; 6];
e = [7; 8; 9; 0];
```

I need to make the program choose four out of the five vectors (in any order) and find the determinant.

Any help at all will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don’t put columns in separate variables, because now you need to access a random subset of variables, which is hard to do. It is much easier to keep the matrix as an actual matrix, and index its columns. Read here about indexing matrices: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Comment: You can compute the determinant with `det`.

Comment: `det([a b c d])` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To control which columns the determinant is applied on, combine the columns into a single matrix, then choose the columns using indexing via `cols`

```
M = [a b c d e];
cols = [1 3 4 5];
det(M(:,cols))
```